# Why to use `Try` in for-comprehension?

Tags: scala, exception, functional-programming, try-catch, monads

While dealing with error-handling in Scala, I came to the point where I asked myself, whether `Try`s in a for-comprehension make sense.

Please regard the unit test given below. This test shows two approaches:

1. The first approach (with `call`) embeds the methods `fooA` and `fooB`, which return regular `String`s, into a `Try` construct.
2. The second approach (`tryCall`) uses a for-comprehension that uses methods `tryFooA` and `tryFooB`, which return `Try[String]` each.

**For what reason should one prefer the for-comprehension variant with `tryCall` over the `call`-variant?**

```
test("Stackoverflow post: Try and for-comprehensions.") {

  val iae = new IllegalArgumentException("IAE")
  val rt = new RuntimeException("RT")

  import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

  def fooA(x1: Int) : String = {
    println("fooA")
    if (x1 == 1) "x1 is 1" else throw iae
  }

  def fooB(x2: Int) : String = {
    println("fooB")
    if (x2 == 1) "x2 is 1" else throw rt
  }

  def tryFooA(x1: Int) : Try[String] = {
    Try {
      println("tryFooA")
      if (x1 == 1) "x1 is 1" else throw iae
    }
  }

  def tryFooB(x2: Int) : Try[String] = {
    Try {
      println("tryFooB")
      if (x2 == 1) "x2 is 1" else throw rt
    }
  }

  def call( x1: Int, x2: Int ) : Try[String] = {
    val res: Try[String] = Try{
      val a = fooA(x1)
      val b = fooB(x2)
      a + " " + b
    }
    res
  }

  def tryCall( x1: Int, x2: Int ): Try[String] = {
    for {
      a <- tryFooA(x1)
      b <- tryFooB(x2)
    } yield (a + " " + b)
  }

  assert( call(0,0) === tryCall(0,0))
  assert( call(0,1) === tryCall(0,1))
  assert( call(1,0) === tryCall(1,0))
  assert( call(1,1) === tryCall(1,1))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of `Try` is to let the compiler help you (and anyone else who uses your code) handle and reason about errors more responsibly.

In your examples, the behavior of `call` and `tryCall` are more or less identical, and if the `fooA`, etc. methods were not part of any public API, there'd be little reason to prefer one over the other.

The advantage of `Try` is that it lets you compose operations that can fail in a clear, concise way. The signatures of `tryFooA` and `tryFooB` are upfront about the fact that they may result in (recoverable) failure, and the compiler makes sure that anyone who calls those methods *must* deal with that possibility. The signatures of `fooA` and `fooB` aren't self-documenting in this way, and the compiler can't provide any assurances that they'll be called responsibly.

These are good reasons to prefer the `tryFoo` signatures. The downside is that callers have to deal with the extra overhead of using `map`, `flatMap`, etc., instead of working with the results (if they exist) directly. The `for`-comprehension syntax is an attempt to minimize this overhead—you get the safety provided by `Try` with only a little extra syntactic overhead.